# Using naked domain with blogger.com

Tags: dns, blogger, blogspot

I am trying to add a custom domain to my blogspot blog. But it is not allowing me to add the naked domain. Is there a way we can use the domain `example.com` with blogger.com instead of `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way for the final url to remain naked.
But you can set a redirect inside the blogger domain settings.

- Edit the domain
  [image: Edit the domain]
- Check the redirect naked to `www` box.
  [image: check the redirect checkbox]

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a bug which allowed you to attach the naked domain to Blogger by adding an extra space in front of the domain while adding it in Settings ( As you see detailed in this article - http://mystady.com/2011/01/solved-blogs-may-not-be-hosted-at-naked.html ) Also, using this bug, few people did successfully attach their naked domain to Blogger (like the site mentioned above as well as blogs like http://thehackernews.com/ )

But that bug was later fixed and there are currently no known workarounds to link the naked domain with Blogger